# Susy math always makes elements too large

Tags: sass, susy

I'm trying to use Susy but I can not create a desirable grid. I want a fixed gutter grid with the gutters coming after the element, not before. I couldn't get that to work. It seems that no matter what I do the elements are too large and the last column falls to the next line.

See this gist:
http://sassmeister.com/gist/6ebf5ec14f697f8d137c

In this basic three column layout each 1/3 width column is over 35% wide. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I only see `width: 28.57143%;` in your sassmeister output. The problem is actually caused by your `border` on all the elements. That adds several extra pixels to the layout, forcing it to break. You can either remove the borders, or add `box-sizing: border-box` so that borders no longer add to the element width. Susy has a `border-box-sizing` mixin that will apply that globally, if you want.